# Why are there multiple versions of Unicode? Why isn't everything UTF-8?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

Again and again, I keep asking myself: ***Why do they always insist on over-complicating everything?!***

I've tried to read up about and understand Unicode many times over the years. When they start talking about endians and BOMs and all that stuff, my eyes just "zone out". I physically cannot keep reading and retain what I'm seeing. I fundamentally don't get their desire for over-complicating everything.

Why do we need UTF-16 and UTF-32 and "big endian" and "little endian" and BOMs and all this nonsense? Why wasn't Unicode just defined as "compatible with ASCII, but you can also use multiple bytes to represent all these further characters"? That would've been nice and simple, but nooo... let's have all this other stuff so that Microsoft chose UTF-16 for Windows NT and nothing is easy or straight-forward!

As always, there probably *is* a reason, but I doubt it's good enough to justify all this confusion and all these problems arising from insisting on making it so complex and difficult to grasp.

Comment: Like any other standard, it starts out simple, grows, and gets complicated due to backward compatibility.

Comment: even ASCII was a mess, as soon as it left the US. that's why Unicode

Comment: [1] Perhaps you are conflating two separate things? Unicode itself is simply a **character set** with defined mappings (`W`  is assigned the code point 87, etc.), whereas UTF-16 and UTF-32 are **encoding schemes** for Unicode. Truly getting that absolutely fundamental distinction is crucial to understanding the big picture. [2] The article [Unicode is Kind of Insane](https://www.benfrederickson.com/unicode-insanity/) may be helpful, especially this comment: _"Human language is a complicated messy business, and Unicode has to be equally complicated to represent it"_.

Comment: "*Why wasn't Unicode just defined as "compatible with ASCII, but you can also use multiple bytes to represent all these further characters"?*" - for one thing, ASCII is 7-bit, so it can only handle 128 characters, whereas Unicode defines *thousands* of characters. There are hundreds of 7-bit/8-bit encodings to represent additional Unicode characters beyond the ASCII characters, commonly known as *codepages*. And there are many *multi-byte* 8-bit encodings. Trust me, dealing with these encodings is an even bigger mess than just dealing with a few UTFs.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode started out as a 16-bit character set, so naturally every character was simply encoded as two consecutive bytes. However, it quickly became clear that this would not suffice, so the limit was increased. The problem was that some programming languages and operating systems had already started implementing Unicode as 16-bit and they couldn’t just throw out everything they had already built, so a new encoding was devised that stayed backwards-compatible with these 16-bit implementations while still allowing full Unicode support. This is UTF-16.

UTF-32 represents every character as a sequence of four bytes, which is utterly impractical and virtually never used to actually store text. However, it is very useful when implementing algorithms that operate on individual codepoints – such as the various mechanisms defined by the Unicode standard itself – because all codepoints are always the same length and iterating over them becomes trivial, so you will sometimes find it used internally for buffers and such.

UTF-8 meanwhile is what you actually want to use to store and transmit text. It is compatible with ASCII and self-synchronising (unlike the other two) and it is quite space-efficient (unlike UTF-32). It will also never produce eight binary zeroes in a row (unless you are trying to represent the literal NULL character) so UTF-8 can safely be used in legacy environments where strings are null-terminated.

Endianness is just an intrinsic property of data types where the smallest significant unit is larger than one byte. Computers simply don’t always agree in what order to read a sequence of bytes. For Unicode, this problem can be circumvented by including a Byte Order Mark in the text stream, because if you read its byte representation in the wrong direction in UTF-16 or UTF-32, it will produce an invalid character that has no reason to ever occur, so you know that this particular order cannot be the right one.